# Is it Possible to Assign Permissions Within a Content Structure

Tags: users, security

I'd like to be able to assign permissions to content or sections of content within a structure. For example, if I have a structure modeled around an organization and there are several departments within that organization, maybe marketing and sales, I'd like to be able to create groups that can create/edit content within a specific department. Is it possible, using a plugin or by some other means, to restrict access to a specific area within a larger structure?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no native way to do this, but you could:

- ...split the [structure](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries) into multiple [channels](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries).
- ...[write a plugin](https://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction) which checks: on what page a user is, and denies access if necessary
- ...ask P&T to add this as a feature.